# Subversion: How do I commit a Update To Revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a situation where:

- Developer is working on SVN project.
- Person checks out SVN project, walks away, kid/cat/wife sits/dools/sleepwalks/whatever at computer and inserts gobbledygook asdfg-code. Person commits project.
- Developer sees bad files and Update To Revision back to the last working version

All is well untill the developer wants to commit the project. If the developer has made changes to the file in question, it will be committed just fine. BUT if not - the dev only Update To Revision and made no further changes - that file will not be commited, and any updates to the project will render the  gobbledygook asdfg-code file to you.

**Question** : If I only 'Update To Revision' a file, how do I commit it again without manually editing the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have chosen the wrong route around the problem.

Rather than changing what revision you are looking at, you should have:

1. Updated to latest revision including the rubbish
2. found the rubbish commit on the revision log and chosen revert this change
3. committed the cleanup with or without any other changes you had to your working copy

So what you would do now is to update to the latest version (applying the rubbish change) and revert their change which brings you back in line.  Pretty much as if they made the change while you where working and didn't have the change in the first place.

You can only commit when your code is up to date with the head of the working branch/trunk.

SVN won't make a branch for you dynamically at this point of earlier revision, you have to choose to make a branch, or to update to the head.

Comment: SO there is no way at all to commit the file again which was updated to a certain revision?

Comment: @Rob: It is impossible to retroactively change revisions. That's sort of a major point of version control...

Comment: (How) Can step 2 ("revert this change") be done using the svn command-line client?

Comment: depends on your command line client somewhat - see [the following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2907754/37558) for an example

Comment: Your method works* (thanks!), but I'm still confused: Why does this method work differently than the one the OP described? Intuitively, I would think that "Update to Revision..." _should_ do the same thing. (But it doesn't, as the OP explained. Why not?)

Comment: *there is a caveat to your solution: if a user has inadvertantly committed unwanted stuff to their branch _more than once_, you would need to change step 2 to: "Find the _last un-altered version of the file_ in the revision log and choose `Revert to this Revision`."

Comment: Ahh, I just found an explanation that resolved my confusion in the first paragraph of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/814547/93394)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on windows, and are using TortoiseSVN:

1. Right click on the dir, select "TortoiseSVN > Merge..."
2. Select "Merge a range of revisions"
3. In "Url to merge from" select the current branch (the one which is checked out in the current dir)
4. In "Revision range to merge" type or select ("Show log") the latest **wrong** revision
5. Mark "Reverse merge" checkbox

Then after the merge, just commit! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply undo changes by using the following

```
svn merge -c -RevisionWhichWasWrong ^/trunk
```

The RevisionWhichWasWrong is the latest which you've checked in. After that simply do

```
svn commit
```

and that's it.

BTW: It's not posssible to checkin if you have never made changes to the contents of files.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! As far as i know it's only possible by manually adding a white space or something to the file so subversion sees the file as changed. After that it creates a new revision.

Answer (score 0):

1- Update to special version that you want to be the last version.

2- Export this version to a folder.

3- Update working copy to last version.

4- Overwrite exported files and folders into working copy folder.

5- Commit!