# How to save/restore local changes at SVN

Tags: svn

How can I save my all local changes in SVN, revert them, and then restore them later?

Comment: Yes, i read. I have found how to revert/update but how save-restore local changes i didn't see( I am using Version 1.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you describe is sometimes called shelving or stashing. Subversion does not offer it.

It's possible to simulate it with patches:

1. You create a patch
2. You revert changes
3. You work on something else and commit
4. You apply the previously created patch

Some editors like NetBeans [can do it for you](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/netbeans-71-ide-shelve-and-un-shelve.html) transparently. There're also third-party scripts.

Optionally, you can create a temporary branch, commit your pending changes there, switch back to previous branch and finally port changes back (`svn merge`) when you're done.

Aside from raw Subversion, it's possible to have this feature with some of your helper tools. For example, TortoiseSVN [has it](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-shelving.html) and so do JetBrains IDEs like [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html). Those are local features so they won't be visible in other Subversion clients, but they can work for you.

Comment: I would also note that step 4 can cause a conflict (it's very similar to a svn update).  Not that that's a bad thing...

Comment: Although SVN doesn't support shelving, TortoiseSVN does.

Answer (score 0):

When you commit your changes, they are saved to a revision number. Save it to revert to it later.

Here is an answer to explain how to revert to older revisions:

[How do I return to an older version of our code in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814433/how-do-i-return-to-an-older-version-of-our-code-in-subversion)

Comment: I now how revert changes and how to commit my changes. But now after my changes i see that some unit test dont work and i want to check wether they were failed before my changes. So i want:    1) to save my changes. 2)revert original code and run unit tests 3)restore locally saved changes

Comment: When you commit your changes, they are saved to a revision number. Even if you revert to an older version of the code, you can always revert back to your most recent version (the one you just committed)

Comment: I don't want to commit changes for now... maybe there is an error - unit tests dont work and i dont know wether the problem in my code or it was before

Comment: Well just do a checkout of the version you want to test, test it and delete it? Like, in a new folder?

Comment: Yes i did so if i understand your right. But it is inconveniently because affected items are in different folders and the directory structure is  very complicated... so manual coping takes much time

Comment: I see, but thats the only way i see. That and making a revision to save your changes, and then delete your new revision when your tests are made, I'm sorry I can't think of anything else.