# Revert central SVN repo from git-svn

Tags: version-control, git-svn

Basically, I would like to [revert a central SVN repository back to a previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814433/how-do-i-return-to-an-older-version-of-our-code-in-subversion), kinda like this:

```
svn update
svn merge -r 150:140 .
svn commit -m "Rolled back to r140"
```

But I'm using `git-svn` and cannot seem to find an equivalent.

I've tried setting everything up locally on a new branch by checking out an earlier commit that was an ancestor of `trunk` (the current commit of the central repo). I made a few additional changes and now I cannot `git svn rebase` or `git svn dcommit` without getting an error from SVN.

I tried checking out that same commit without making the additional changes and then running `git svn dcommit`, this says it is committing to the central repo but doesn't actually seem to do anything.

How do I go back to a previous commit and then start making new changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is essentially to reset your git HEAD into the state of r140, but in a way that would allow a straightforward `git svn dcommit`.

One way of doing this:

```
# checkout git revision of the desired state
git svn find-rev r140 | xargs git checkout

# reset HEAD to the revision 150, assuming it was the latest svn commit in trunk 
git reset trunk
git add -u
git commit -m "Rolled back to r140"
git svn dcommit
```

You could also take a look on thread [Revert multiple git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits)