# Back out changes in SVN

Tags: svn

I made a bunch of changes to my project and at the end of the day I'm not happy with it.  I never committed my changes, so I just want to go back to my last revision.

I checked the current revision using svn info and it said it is revision 110.  Then I tried svn update -r 110, but it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Anyone know how I can get back to my last committed rev?

Comment: look like this SO question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814433/how-do-i-return-to-an-older-version-of-our-code-in-subversion could be even a duplicate.

Comment: @AndreasA. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, that seems a bit different.  I never committed any of the changes I've made. So I'm not reverting from one committed revision to another, like that question is asking about.

Comment: oh ok then sorry my bad....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svn revert -R .
```

That reverts all files.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to obliterate your changes, try and use: `svn revert <file-name>`