# Reverting changes failed with some skipped paths

Tags: svn, merge, revert

I've read this answer: [How do I return to an older version of our code in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814433/how-do-i-return-to-an-older-version-of-our-code-in-subversion) and used the command `svn merge -r 150:140 .` to revert back to an old revision (I didn't need to commit the reverted changes, just get to the old version of files). Before that I had a clean version of repo at revision 150 (no manual changes to files). Unfortunately, I got these warnings:

```
...
Skipped 'some/file.h'
Skipped 'some/file2.h'
...
Skipped 'some/file3.h'
Skipped 'some/file4.h'
...
Summary of conflicts:
Skipped paths: 4
```

Which surprises me seeing as all I wanted to do was go back to some old version of files (and I had no changes beforehand).

What could have caused this? How do I get to the old version?

Edit: I've checked and apparently these files don't exist in the currrent version (150) (either on disk or in SVN):

```
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'some/file.h' was not found.
```

But they did exist in revision 140. So somewhere along the way they were deleted. But why can't SVN just restore them?

Comment: Were there file renames? Subversion does not cope well with renames.

Comment: No, these files were just removed.

Comment: What is the output of `svn stat`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this repository anymore - had to move forward at my work. So I'm afraid we can't continue this thread. But I don't think I can close the bounty right now.

Comment: It can be caused by a merge conflict that you postponed, then you deleted the file locally, now it wont check out the file, wont update it, and skips it.

Answer (score 5):

The most common root cause for such a tree conflict is, that your working copy had some changes and then you try to merge - bad things can happen. Just guessing from the output, it could be related to the "some" folder (i.e. if the whole folder was removed between revision 140 and 150 - not just the files; or if you had some local changes in the skipped files before merging).

In case this happens in the future again, try to revert the failed merge by executing:

```
svn revert --recursive
```

Back on revision 150 delete any unversioned files & folders from your working copy and rerun the merge by using

```
svn merge -r 150:140 -v --force .
```

(`-v` will display more verbose information, `--force` will delete files from your working copy, even if they were modified local)

In case everything else fails, the last resort is always to just checkout a fresh working copy from revision 140 into a new local folder using

```
svn checkout -r 140 $your_url
```

Comment: "Before that I had a clean version of repo at revision 150 (no manual changes to files)."

Comment: Without more information on the svn changes and the working copy status, we can only guess what the root cause really was

Comment: I know, I wrote that in the comment to my question.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got any upvotes - we may not be able to find the root cause but I explicitly stated that the repo was a clean checkout with no modifications and this answer points to modifications as the potential root cause.