# Move a part of SVN branch to another branch, replace stub

Tags: svn

In the application I work on, I began developing a new feature. At the moment I started, I lacked the foresight of how large a feature that would be - that it would definitely grant its own branch in the repository. Then a client reported a bug in a release from before I began working on that feature, and I quickly checked the revision out, fixed the bug, got it through testing, and... uh. I don't exactly know how to check it in now so that I don't break *everything*

r34 is far from stable currently, and likely won't be any soon. Meanwhile the branch needs to be open for hotfixes.  So the smart approach would be to move all that work starting with the first commit introducing the big feature to a separate branch. And simultaneously *not lose* the local copy with the bugfix, but commit it as the head of the r10 branch.

This is what it looks like...
[image]

How can I do this without breaking anything (any more than it is already)?

Comment: Why don't you perform a cherry-pick merge?

Comment: @bahrep: quite possible on the bugfix, but the feature in a short time sprawled over way too many files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a patch between r34 and r33
2. [revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814433/how-do-i-return-to-an-older-version-of-our-code-in-subversion) branch 10 to r33
3. create branch 11 from the new commit
4. apply patch to the new branch 11
5. commit local copy to branch 10